# How to ensure javascript is included only once when used inside an ASCX

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ascx

I've an ASCX includes a javascript. If I use this ASCX more than once on a page I have the javascript definition repeated.

Is there a standard clean way to prevent this without define it on a masterpage?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) class. Specifically the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `RegisterClientScriptInclude` methods.